# Let $S^2$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $e^3=(0,0,1)$. Show that $X:= S^2\setminus \{e_3, -e_3\}$ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S^2$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $e^3=(0,0,1)$. Show that $X:= S^2\setminus \{e_3, -e_3\}$ is not compact by exhibiting an open cover which does not admit a finite subcover.

My attempt: One can project down the sphere on the plane via sterographic projection.

But I cannot procced further. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of any compact space under a continuous function is compact. However, the image of the projection is unbounded.

To find an open cover that doesn't have a finite subcover, let $U_n  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be $\{\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||\vec{v}|| < n \}$. Then, the preimage of $U_n$ in $S^3 \backslash (e_3, -e_3)$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimensional spaces compact sets are closed and bounded (Heine-Borel). Taking $x_{n}=(0,0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ we have a sequence in the set S-{$e_{3},-e_{3}$} which converges to (0,0,1) which does not belong to the set. Therefore the set is not closed and hence not compact! Using covers now, consider the open sets $U_{n}=\{ (x,y,z):x^{2}+y^{2}+(z-1)^{2}\gt \frac{1}{n^{2}} \}$. Since $\left| z-1 \right|\gt \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is always an n such that (x,y,z) $\in $ $\bigcup_{n}^{}U_{n}$. Thus  S-{$e_{3},-e_{3}$}  is covered by the union but it is NOT covered by any finite subcover. That completes the proof!!

Answer (score 1):

More generally if $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $x\in X$ is not isolated then $X\backslash \{x\}$ is not compact. This is simply because there is a net $(x_\alpha)$ convergent to $x$ totally contained in $X\backslash \{x\}$. And thus it has no convergent subnet in $X\backslash \{x\}$, by uniqueness of limits in Hausdorff spaces.

The above should be applied to for example $X=S^2\backslash\{e_3\}$ and $x=-e_3$.